# NativeScript tns create fails - At POSTINSTALL Script

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I try to create a new project with the following command, the folders first get created and by the end gets deleted. The project is NOT created finally. I just see a package-lock.json at the end

I'm editing this post with a pattern I've recently been seeing.
Just for a Change I tried doing TNS CREATE with VUE JS, it fails exactly in the POSTINSTALL JS script.

Any idea what I can do to get rid of this issue. This has been wasting my time for over 2 days now.

Here is the log

EDIT --- NEW LOG WITH Node Version 10
Eshcols-iMac:NativeScript eshcol$ sudo tns create

## Let’s create a NativeScript app!

Answer the following questions to help us build the right app for you. (Note: you
can skip this prompt next time using the --template option, or the --ng, --vue, --ts,
or --js flags.)

? First, what will be the name of your app? TestApp

? Next, which style of NativeScript project would you like to use: Angular

? Finally, which template would you like to start from: Hello World

> fsevents@1.2.7 install /Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents
>   node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib' 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/bin/node" "/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)

> nativescript-angular@7.1.2 postinstall /Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/nativescript-angular
>   node postinstall.js

fs.js:115
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/hooks'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:753:3)
    at Object. (/Users/eshcol/NativeScript/TestApp/node_modules/nativescript-angular/postinstall.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nativescript-angular@7.1.2 postinstall: `node postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nativescript-angular@7.1.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/eshcol/.npm/_logs/2019-02-02T15_47_24_931Z-debug.log
Command npm failed with exit code 1

## tns create

Comment: Node v11 is not supported yet, you might want to downgrade your node version to v10.x

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Please check out the Node 10 log ... same case.
I feel like giving up on NativeScript  and live with Ionic till they come up with a stable solution ... this is wasting my time

Answer (score 0):

To fix project creation in general you can try `sudo chown -R username /home/username/.npm` This should allow you to run `tns create MyApp` without adding `sudo`.